# How to mock method calls of some object which is passed as method parameter of method under JUnit Test

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am writing JUnit for some legacy class which I can't change. The Problem which I am facing is as follows

```
public class B{
public String method2() {
    //fetch some data from database and return it
}
```

}

```
public class A{
public String myMethod(B b) {
    return b.method2();
}
```

}

how can I mock the call for method2 in junit using mockito

Comment: method2 isn't even valid Java. it won't compile, so it won't run, and you won't be able to mock it

Comment: now I have corrected the mistake. now please tell me what could be a possible solution for the problem

Comment: use Mockito, actually mock B, and pass that as param to your method in Class A. Or, create your own class that Mocks B, and pass that as parameter to the method in class A during testing

Comment: could you please explain using some example code just the basic idea

Comment: @StavShamir worst idea ever. if you need to change A to test it, you're doing it wrong

Comment: No I can't Its legacy code for which I have to increase the coverage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class B2 extends B { // so, this is, in fact, an IS-A of B
  public String method2() {
    return "mockedResult";
  }
}
```

In your test, you'll now have something like this:

```
@Test
public void testMethod() {
  A toTest = new A();
  assertEquals("mockedResult", toTest.myMethod(new B2());
}
```

This is the very simplistic way. But I would recommend to read up on a Mocking framework, such as Mockito for more complex scenario's.

https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-series

By using Mockito, for short, it would be something like this:

```
public class TestClass {

  @Mock
  private B b;

  private A toTest = new A();

  @Test
  public void testMethod() {
    when(b.method2()).thenReturn("mockedResult");
    assertEquals("mockedResult", toTest.myMethod());
  }
}
```

Comment: so I have to extend the class and mock those methods which we have to mock

Comment: OP is asking for how to mock it with Mockito... Which would simply be to pass a mock of `B` to `myMethod()`.

Comment: @Magnilex yes. that would mean first knowing how to Mock using Mockito. So, I could either vote to close the question since it's basically asking for a tutorial, or provide a simplistic version that shows the concept (which he asked for in the comments) and provide a link to a mockito tutorial

Comment: @NipulSindwani No, not if you want to use Mockito. but explaining Mockito is too much to put in a SO answer, so I've added a link to a series of tutorials where Mockito is explained

Comment: @NipulSindwani I am not disagreeing to any of that, just pointed it out in case you missed it.

Comment: I know how to mock using mockito, I had dealt with when().thenReturn/verify stuffs. but I was stuck at this particular scenario

Comment: I have got some idea through this discussion I will try It. Thanks a lot

Comment: @NipulSindwani I've added a simple Mockito example

Comment: if this answers your question, can you marked it as solved?

Comment: how can I do it I am not aware of that

Comment: Ok I will do It once I successfully implement the solution of yours , otherwise I will comeback here with any further query which I may face.